# Cannot insert a quotelineitem in my Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, test-setup

I try to insert a quotelineitem in my test class but it fails with this error ,Please help me to resolve this issue .

[image]
See below my code used in the test class

```
Quote quote = new Quote(Name = 'devis1' ,OpportunityId=opp.Id  );
       insert quote;
Product2 pr1 = new Product2(Name = 'Service Internet sur Fibre Dédiée');
        insert pr1;
PriceBookEntry pre = new PriceBookEntry(PriceBook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(), Product2Id = pr1.Id , UnitPrice=123);
        insert pre;
QuoteLineItem qiItem = new  QuoteLineItem(QuoteId = quote.Id ,Product2Id=pr1.Id  ,PricebookEntryId=pre.Id, Quantity =1 , UnitPrice=123 );
       insert  qiItem; //line failed
```

Comment: Please always include error message as ***text***, rather than as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your mocking of the Quote to include the Pricebook2Id

```
Quote quote = new Quote(Name = 'devis1' ,
                        OpportunityId=opp.Id,
                        Pricebook2Id =  Test.getStandardPricebookId() );
insert quote;
```

Change your mocking of the `PricebookEntry` to make the PBE *active*.

from:

```
PriceBookEntry pre = new PriceBookEntry(
      PriceBook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(), 
      Product2Id = pr1.Id , 
      UnitPrice=123);
insert pre;
```

to:

```
PriceBookEntry pre = new PriceBookEntry(
         IsActive = true,
         PriceBook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(), 
         Product2Id = pr1.Id , 
         UnitPrice=123);
insert pre;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,good answer ,my problem was resolved